# chef/ruby include method not matching, troubleshooting help requested

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm new to chef and ruby and I'm trying to implement a chef recipe that removes files from a directory where those files don't exist in my cookbook:

```
ruby_block 'cleandir' do
block do
  Dir.foreach('/tmp/conf.d') do |item|
    next if item.include?("#{node['logstash']['conf']['filelist']}") or item == '.' or item == '..'
    # do work on real items
    puts "deleting #{item}"
    #File.delete("#{item}")
    end
  end
end
```

I define attributes:

```
default['logstash']['conf']['filelist'] = [
'01-input-01-filebeat.conf',
'11-filter-01-syslog.conf',
'11-filter-02-iptables_geoip.conf',
'11-filter-03-named_querylog.conf',
'49-output-mail_01-grokparsefailure.conf',
'49-output-mail_02-error.conf',
'50-output.conf',
'51-output-stdout.conf'
]
```

This results in the following output:

```
deleting 49-output-mail_02-error.conf
deleting 11-filter-01-syslog.conf
deleting 80-output.conf
deleting 50-output.conf
deleting 49-output-mail_01-grokparsefailure.conf
deleting 11-filter-03-named_querylog.conf
deleting 11-filter-02-iptables_geoip.conf
deleting 51-output-stdout.conf
deleting 01-input-01-filebeat.conf
```

The expected output should just be `deleting 80-output.conf` as its the only file that isn't part of the node attribute array.

I don't understand why the include? method isn't matching, how can I further troubleshoot?

@Sebastian Your suggestion worked:

```
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["logstashConfig::clean_conf"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - logstashConfig (0.0.4)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: logstashConfig::clean_conf
  * ruby_block[cleandir] action run
deleting 80-output.conf

    - execute the ruby block cleandir

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 1/1 resources updated in 02 seconds`
```

Thank you Sebastian and coderanger!

## #

So here's my solution so far, thanks to @Sebastian and @coderanger:

```
ruby "cleandir" do
  (Dir.entries("#{node['logstash']['conf']['path']}") - node['logstash']['conf']['filelist']).each do |name|
    next if node['logstash']['conf']['filelist'].include?(name) or name == '.' or name == '..'
    FileUtils.rm "#{node['logstash']['conf']['path']}/#{name}", :verbose => true
    notifies :restart, 'service[restart_logstash]', :delayed
  end
end
```

I don't know that this is the best or most efficient way but it does what I need, which is to delete files not part of the cookbook, and restart the service if any are found and deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define `default['logstash']['conf']['filelist']` as an array of strings, and item is a single one, then you could try with something like:

```
next if node['logstash']['conf']['filelist'].include?(item) || item =~ /\./
  ...
```

The `item == '.' or item == '..'` could be simplified with `item =~ /\./`.

Comment: `next if node['logstash']['conf']['filelist'].include?(item)` works.


`item =~ /\./` seemed to also prevent matching 80-output.conf, 0 results returned.

Comment: My bad, I didn't think about it, maybe with something like `/^\.{1,2}[a-zA-Z0-9]+/`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `zap` cookbook for a possibly better implementation of this. The general pattern in Chef is called an "accumulator" and is often very tricky to implement correctly, but `zap` is a starting point at least. Alternatively you can do something like this:

```
(Dir.entries("/tmp/conf.d") - node['logstash']['conf']['filelist']).each do |name|
  ::File.unlink("/tmp/conf.d/#{name}")
end
```

using set operations on the Arrays to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: So this returns `.` and `..`  as well but works when used with the `next if` statement from above.

Comment: Yeah, or `(Dir.entries("/tmp/conf.d") - node['logstash']['conf']['filelist'] - %w{. ..})`